# Am I right by changing the default algorithm on a web app?

Tags: hash, sql-injection

Numerous clients have told me that my suggestion on changing the algorithm on a web app does not increase security. I've tried reasoning that if the files have not been exposed, the attacker has to guess at the algorithm.

A few days ago I was assessing a friend's site and pointed out a few SQLi vulnerabilities. I didn't have any access to the files. Like above, my friend told me I was wrong to suggest a different algorithm even though he can handle the trade offs to a different algorithm.

My reasoning with him was that an attacker wouldn't know your algorithm so you ruled out a minority of attackers just by changing algo. If they used a tool like hashcat and tried to crack the hash with a preset, it wouldn't lead them anywhere. Even though this is security through obscurity, it works in a way that you defended yourself just a little if you have another SQLi.

He insisted on not changing the algorithm because anyone who exploits the site is an automatic white flag. He assumes that if a hash is retrieved, everyone will take the time to crack it.

The default hash is md5. I suggested PBKDF2 or bcrypt.

Just as a double opinion:
Who, in theory and actuality, is correct in this situation?

Is it correct that he should put up a white flag if someone retrieves an admin's hash?
Would I be correct in saying this is a practical use of security through obscurity?... Or if it's not security through obscurity at all?

Answer (score 6):

Changing the algorithm "because the attacker will not know it" is a *very poor reason* for changing an algorithm. To begin with, the attacker may infer that you will use an algorithm for which support exists in the code, which limits the possible choices, and the algorithm can then often be disambiguated based on what can be seen on the output (if the output is 160 bits, that's SHA-1, not MD5).

It would be a severe delusion that changing the algorithm really brings, by that "attacker won't guess it" reasoning, significantly increased security. Algorithms cannot be assumed to be secret, because information about the algorithm leaks everywhere: in the code, in the code *behaviour* (e.g. execution time), in the head of developers... and the space of possible algorithms is tiny.

Now changing from MD5 to PBKDF2 or bcrypt is a *very good idea*. Not because the attacker would assume that it is MD5 and "never guess" that bcrypt was used; in fact, bcrypt's output tends to be obvious in that respect (they have a specific encoding of output + salt as a string which states clearly that bcrypt was used). But because a basic MD5 is a *terrible* way to hash passwords. If you want to store hashed passwords, at least [do it correctly](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846), which means, right now, PBKDF2 or bcrypt.